# Regex - how to select a set of characters from the back up to the second slash?

Tags: regex

I have this string:

```
https://picsum.photos/id/1005/5760/3840
```

And I want to extract `/5760/3840`, so everything from the end of the string up to the second slash.

So far I have this expression: /[\d].*$/g, which is selecting all the digits ("1005/5760/3840"). I've looked at the solutions for similar problems, but none of them seem to work for the back-search. Any hints?

Comment: What should happen for something like `https://picsum.photos/id/1005/5760/3840/`?

Answer (score 1):

Try "digits, a slash, more digits, end of string", i.e.

```
/\d+\/\d+$/
```

Answer (score 1):

The direct translation would be

```
(?:/[^/]+){2}$
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/lznUxQ/1/).
Depending on the actual programming language, you might need to escape the forward slashes to

```
(?:\/[^\/]+){2}$
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep something similar to what you proposed, you can use:

`\/[0-9]*\/[0-9]*$`